# Using i18n in Mixin?

Tags: ember.js, ember-i18n

Is there a way to use i18n in Mixin. I'd like to create Mixins as configurations for my fields, and I need to translate labels, but as far as I've read https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n/wiki/Doc:-i18n-Service I don't see an opportunity to implement that.

Comment: You can inject the service into your mixin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kitler noted, you can inject the i18n service to your mixins, so you can use them in your components.

```
export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  i18n: Ember.inject.service(),

  translate: function(key, options) {
    return this.get('i18n').t(key, options);
  }
});
```

What do you expect more? Do you want to modify all of the labels as [Decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)? If you want to do decorate label of a component by a mixin than you should do:

```
export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  i18n: Ember.inject.service(),

  translate: function(key, options) {
    return this.get('i18n').t(key, options);
  },

  init(){ //init or didReceiveAttrs 
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('label', this.translate(this.get('label')));
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you and kitler too. I was trying to inject i18n to Mixin, but I had no success because of typo. Now everything works!